# bottom part cannot be shown using using django-crispy-forms

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I am trying to create form view using django-crispy-view.
Even though I could implement form view following [the doc](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html), submit button cannot be shown (as shown below) even though I can confirm submit button zooming out to 50%.
Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

**forms.py**

class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super(DocumentForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.helper=FormHelper(self)
    self.helper.form_id='projectForm'
    self.helper.form_method='post'
    self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
```

**html template**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% crispy document_form document_form.helper %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/form.css' %}" />

{% block content %}
    <h3>Upload Project</h3>
    {% crispy form %}
{% endblock %}
```

**from.css**

```
#projectForm{
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to show us your code - how else can we help you figure out where you're going wrong? Also note that crispy forms will not automatically render a submit button - you have to add it to the layout.

Comment: I added code. And I added submit button as shown the code and can see the button when I zoom out. However, cannot scroll down enough to see submit button in normal view

Comment: If you can see it when you zoom out, then the issue is with styling - maybe you have set a fixed height on the body or some other wrapping element, and overflow is hidden.

Comment: I created css file specifying 'margin-bottom' to show submit button as shown updated code. However, it seems that this css setting is not applied when I check in chrome developper tool. Do you know why css is not applied to this form?